# Continuity of a constant function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

If f assumes only finite many values, then f is continuous at a point $x_0$ if and only if f is constant on some interval $(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)$

I know how to prove continuity for a given interval but I am having trouble with proving it is constant. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If $f$ assumes only finitely many values, can different values be really close to each other?

Comment: Yes. I know different intervals can be chosen like I_1=[x0−δ,x0−δ+h] and I_2=(x0−δ+h, x0−δ+2h] but don't know where to go from there

Comment: That's not what I was talking about. I was talking about the _values_ that $f$ assumes.

Comment: If f is constant, shouldn't there just be 1 value for f?

Comment: $f$ needn't be constant globally. Under the given conditions, $f$ must however be constant in some neighbourhood of $x_0$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f$ only takes on the values $c_1,\ldots,c_n$.  Suppose that $f(x_0)=c_1$.  Without loss, suppose that $|c_1-c_2|\leq |c_1-c_i|$ for all $i>1$.  Choose $0<\epsilon<|c_1-c_2|$.  Now run the definition of continuity.