# f takes finitely many values, and is continuous at a show that f is constant on an interval nigh of a

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

the question was asked before but I didn't get the hints or the attempted answer in: [Continuity of a constant function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570343/continuity-of-a-constant-function)

Edited: I applied what was mentioned on the link I eneded up with : `

> l f(x)-c1l<= lf(x)l +lc1l <= lc1l +l-c2l simplifying stuff I get : lf(x)-c1l<= lf(x)l -lc2l <=0

`

So I conluded from this that lf(x)-c1l<=0 hence f(x)=c1... f constant  I am not sure that doing this right since I ignored the term lf(x)l -lc2l ??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question   because it is an exact duplicate of the one you  link to. The answer there seems about as straightforward as possible, using the definition of continuity.

Comment: You need to actually explain what issues you are having, otherwise people will vote to close your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Continuity of a constant function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570343/continuity-of-a-constant-function)

Comment: @user505379 I eddited with what I am having problem with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the triangle inequality unless you know what you are doing, because you may lose too much information.

Here, suppose that $f(x_0)=c_1$ for some $x$. If you choose $\varepsilon$ as suggested in the linked question, you  get from continuity that there exists $\delta>0$ such that on the whole interval $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$, you have 
$$\tag1
|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|f(x)-c_1|<\varepsilon<|c_j-c_1|,\ \ \text{ for all } j.
$$
But $f$ takes finitely many values, so $f(x)=c_j$ for some $j$. That makes the inequality in $(1)$ impossible unless $f(x)=c_1$. Thus $f(x)=c_1$ for all $x\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$.